# how to use cloudera manager for monitor the components of CDH4

Tags: cloudera

I have already install CDH4 without using cloudera manager. I wanted to use cloudera manager so that i can monitor the different components of CDH4. Please suggest me how to use the manager now.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had to undertake the same task of importing already installed and running clusters into new Cloudera Manager instances.

I would firstly suggest taking your time to read through as much documentation as possible to fully understand the processes and key components.

As a short answer, you need to manually import all your cluster configurations and assignments into Cloudera Manager so that they can be managed. A rough outline of the plan I used is below:

- Setup MySQL instance on NEW hardware (can use postgresql)
- Create Cloudera Manager user on all servers (must be sudo enabled)
- Setup ssh key access between cloudera-manager server and all other hosts

  - Useful Docs below:
        - http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_mysql.html
        - http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_path_B.html
- Install Cloudera Manager and agent/daemon packages on Cloudera Manager server
- Shutdown all services using cluster and cluster services
- Save the namespace
- Backup Meta Data and Configuration files to MULTIPLE LOCATIONS
- Ensure the backup can be loaded by starting a single instance NN
- Install Cloudera Manager agent and daemon on all production servers
- Start the services on the Cloudera Manager server
- Access the Cloudera Manager interface
- Skip Setup Wizard
- Add all hosts to Cloudera Manager
- Create HDFS service - DO NOT start the service

  - Check hosts assignments are correct
  - Input all configuration file parameters and verify (this means each servers conf files need to be input manually)
  - Run host inspector and configuration check
- Perform the above process for remaining services

I hope this provides a some assistance for you. If you have any other questions I will be happy to try and assist you as much as I can.

Regards,
James

Answer (score 0):

I just recorded a webinar titled "Installing Cloudera Manager in < 30 mins" for Global Knowledge. Available at: http://www.globalknowledge.com/training/coursewebsem.asp?pageid=9&courseid=20221&catid=248&country=United+States (register in the upper right of page). In the video, I install CM on Ubuntu, set up the core components (Hadoop only), and then browse through some of the graphs for monitoring.

Comment: Ahhh.. nevermind... I see you set up CDH4 before using CM (leaving original post in case it helps someone). Eric Sammer wrote a pretty good post on your situation here: https://www.quora.com/Cloudera/Can-we-install-Cloudera-Manager-to-manage-an-existing-cluster